# Как из одной функции переместить переменную в другую?

Tags: python

Знаю, что вопрос тупой, но я только учу пайтон.
Как переменную name переместить в другую функцию?
`

```
def start(message):

    bot.send_message(message.from_user.id, 'Как вас звать')
    bot.register_next_step_handler(message, get_name)
    return name

def alla( message ):
    text = name
    bot.send_message(message.from_user.id, 'Реєстрація закінчена')
    bot.send_message(message.from_user.id, 'Очікуйте на картку')
    user_id = message.from_user.id
    tatras =Image.open(R'C:\Х-\Foto.jpg')
    text1 = 'Ось ваша індивідуальна картка'
    idraw = ImageDraw.Draw(tatras)
    font =  ImageFont.truetype('arial.ttf', size = 48)
    font2 = ImageFont.truetype('arial.ttf', size = 28)
    idraw.text((350, 380), text, font=font)
    idraw.text((900, 10), user_id, font=font2)
    tatras.save(R'hC:\Х-\Foto4.jpg', 'rb')
    img1 = io.open(R'C:\Х-\Foto4.jpg','rb')
    bot.send_photo(photo.from_user.id, img1, caption=text1)
```

Пишет, что не знает переменную name

Comment: а где вы объявляли переменную name??

Comment: @Антон Бандалай ознакомьтесь https://python-scripts.com/scope

Comment: Можно в самом начале кода объявить переменную name , а затем в каждую из функций вписать global name .

Comment: можно прочитать про 'Область видимости в Python' и забыть про эту ошибку

Comment: @ВадимПлатонов Можно, но только один раз. Потому что потом за это оторвут руки.

Comment: Ну да. Просто как вариант.